# How to prevent a Rails app from starting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to make sure there is an env var set when the Rails app starts.

How to prevent the Rails app from starting if the env is not set?

```
if ENV[ 'CONFIG_VAR' ].blank?
   puts 'Cannot start without setting CONFIG_VAR'
   ...
end
```

Also, where is good place to put this code?

Answer (score 3):

You could always raise an exception.

```
if ENV[ 'CONFIG_VAR' ].blank?
   fail 'Cannot start without setting CONFIG_VAR'
end
```

Although it might be nicer to set a default value and print a warning.

```
if ENV[ 'CONFIG_VAR' ].blank?
   warn 'CONFIG_VAR not set! Defaulting to x'
   ENV['CONFIG_VAR'] = x
   ...
end
```

Comment: Although this does work for some deploy environments, it will not work for Heroku because the ENV is not available during slug compilation...

Comment: That may be true, but that is more a weakness of the question than the answer. It probably isn't a good idea, in general, to prevent a Rails app from starting just because an environment variable is missing.